# install custom windows service using group policy to all domain device

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, windows-services, group-policy

I have created a custom windows service project which gather some device information and send it to intranet server.

I'm able to install that service on local computer and working fine.

> But no idea how do i install this custom windows service to my domain
> devices using group policy.
>
> I'm using .NET 4.7.2

Comment: Group Policy is just the group credentals of the application.  To install in the domain you need an Admin Account that allows you to install on Network.  There are different Admin layers and you probably do not have to priviledge to install in the domain.  Group policy is a hight level Admin Account.

Comment: @jdweng i can manage highest level of authorization as admin i just want the way so that i can install it..
thanks for response. !!

Comment: The code should install like any other code provided you are the privilege.  Then you may need to change pledges to let non admins run.